# Docker MySQL server failed

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, arm, debian

I have installed MySQL Server, but when I am running container, I will get error:

```
docker run -it \
-e 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password' \
-e 'MYSQL_DATABASE=identity' \
-e 'MYSQL_USER=identity' \
-e 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=password' \
-p '3306:3306' \
--name example_mysql \
beercan1989/arm-mysql:latest\
```

The output is "There were fatal errors during processing of zoneinfo directory".

I am using debian OS.

Does someone had the same?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate zone tables in mysql database within ubuntu with xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38398302/608639). See Csongor answer and analysis.